# Prevent page refresh in asp.net but not postback by using javascript or asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I used the below mentioned JavaScript code for preventing the page reload but when I am redirecting the page then also it is executing this code. How i can prevent this? I want to execute this code only on page refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            return 'Are you sure you want to reload or leave this page? All progress will be lost.';
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Just remove your postbacks, those are a horrid invention anyway.

Comment: What is the status of this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `isDirty` variable to your page.

- When something is edited, set it to `true`
- Just before submitting (onclick on the button), set it to `false`
- In your beforeunload handler, check this value and only return the message when `isDirty === true`

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the postback function and unbind the beforeunload event in it:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```